# Force evaluation of anonymous type query before storing in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, operator-precedence

I need to bring back several user specific data sets to bind to drop down lists for a search page that is frequently (re)loaded (potentially not being able to utilize postback data). I want to hit the database once and, when necessary, populate the drop down lists from session data instead of getting it from the database again.

When I set the session (last line, below), will it store the evaluated results, or will referencing the session re-run the queries each time? If the later is the case, what is the best way to force evaluation before setting the session while still maintaining the use of anonymous types?

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public IQueryable Results1 { get; set; }
    public IQueryable Results2 { get; set; }
}

public static CustomClass GetResults()
{
    var results1 = (
        from t in Table
        select new
        {
            t.Id,
            t.Value
        };

    var results2 = (
        from t in Table
        select new
        {
            t.Id,
            t.Value
        };

    return 
        new CustomClass
        {
            Results1 = results1,
            Results2 = results2
        };
}

*****

Session["Results"] = GetResults();
```

Comment: I'm not sure knowing the answer would help. How do you plan on using `Session["Results"]` if you cannot cast it back to its original type?

Comment: Maybe you should use `System.Tuple<int, strin>` instead of an anonymous type ? This will allow you to create `IQueryable<Tuple<int,string>>` properties.

Comment: @hvd, var results = (CustomClass) Session["Results"]; ddl.DataSource = results.Results1;

Comment: Ah, okay, so you don't need to access the properties from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.ToList()` on `result1` and `result2`.

```
return  
    new CustomClass 
    { 
        Results1 = results1.ToList(), 
        Results2 = results2.ToList() 
    };
```

Comment: The result of `.ToList()` is only `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`, so that should cause a compiler error.

Comment: So, change the type in `CustomClass`?

Comment: @John Saunders, I don't believe I can change the CustomClass Result types to Lists and still maintain the anonymous types. It is important that I don't need to make strongly typed classes for all of these data sets.

Comment: I meant change them to be `IEnumerable`.